# What does `rpm -qa` do?

Tags: rpm

This page http://rikers.org/rpmbook/node29.html
says "RPM's query function can help you get out of sticky situations"
and `man rpm` says:

```
QUERYING AND VERIFYING PACKAGES:
   rpm {-q|--query} [select-options] [query-options]

   -a, --all
          Query all installed packages.
```

If I run `rpm -qa logstash` I get:

```
logstash-5.5.1-1.noarch
```

so does this mean:

1. I have logstash-5.5.1-1 installed?
2. logstash-5.5.1-1 is available to install from the remote source?
3. a local logstash rpm is available which is logstash-5.5.1-1?

Comment: The next page of the RPM book explains the command in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Used like this, `rpm` will return information about installed packages. This means you have `logstash-5.5.1-1.noarch` installed.

You could gather more information on both the installed and available packages by using `dnf info logstash` (or, on older EL distros, `yum info logstash`).